# There is no xmlns:local in my MainTabbedPage.xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I want to learn Xamarin.forms. Right now I am trying to create a TabbedPage. I already finished the ContentPage. Now I want to add them to the MainTabbedPage.xaml but the problem is that there is no xmlns:local so I can't add the pages.

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="AppNeu.MainTabbedPage">
    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->



</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Add the xmlns:local your self. You can add it. Assign it to the namescape of your project

Comment: It works. Thank u

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if one of the opinions helped solving your problem.

Comment: I have added it as answer could you please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Add the xmlns:local your self. You can add it. Assign it to the namescape of your project.

Comment: @Marco, please do not forget to mark it as answer(click the "✔" in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.